# Kinematic Approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I was recently looking at a physics problem and it kind of confused me:

A 1 kg ball is shot out of a 5m long cannon directly upwards. A constant force of 15 N is used to accelerate the ball out of the cannon. What is the ball's velocity as it leaves the cannon?

I understand how to do this problem with work-energy principles, but apparently there is also a kinematics approach. My confusion comes from the fact that doesn't the force only apply to the initial state (and accelerate it from rest) and after that the acceleration is only from gravity i.e. a=-g? However, in the (kinematic) solution, the net acceleration is found to be: F = ma --> F(applied) - F(grav) = 1(a) --> 15-1(9.8) = 1(a) --> a = 5.2m^2/s. Technically shouldn't the acceleration be non-constant b/c gravity is always present and decreasing the initial acceleration provided by the force (I know that the problem says "constant force" but it still feels like it's an inaccurate/flawed statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a slight misunderstanding with acceleration. In the problem, the ball is propelled out of the cannon with 15 N of force, and gravity is trying to pull it down with 9.8 N of force. These two forces never change: the acceleration of gravity will always be the same no matter how long it is applied to something (evidence, you're not growing heavier with each passing second). The velocity, on the other hand, will change as it moves through the barrel. It will accelerate upwards at 5.2 m/s^2, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question as you quote it, as long as the ball is in the cannon, there are two forces acting on it: the 15 N upwards, and 10 N down (from gravity). This should lead to constant acceleration of 5 m/s$^2$.

Not sure what is confusing you.